# How to allow youtube videos to go fullscreen in QtWebView?

Tags: qt, flash, webkit, qt5, qwebview

I am developing an application using Qt 5.5. It should have an embedded web browser, so I added QtWebView to a form. But if I open a youtube video and click fullscreen button, I see a message "Fullscreen is unavailable" with link leading to [Fullscreen is disabled](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6276924) page.

The page says I must enable fullscreen permissions in the browser.

I have read all of the Qt5 WebKit documentation, but found nothing about that. I also found some close questions here on StackOverflow, but none of them has helping answers.

I wrote a class to replace standard QWebPage class to replace user agent and allow opening links in new windows, and I feel like I have to do something with that class. I tried to override triggerAction function, but it is never called.

If someone had the same problem, please tell me the way to achieve it.

Comment: I found that it will never be ported to QWebView as it is sort of deprecated, regardless it is not said in documentation. Newer, supported component is QWebEngineView, but plugins are not yet implemented in stable version. So, as we see, Qt has no stable version of browser components and developers don't think it is a good thing to tell others about that.